# ImageView rotates only once using AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator

Tags: android, animation, image-rotation

I am trying to rotate an image by 360 degree using AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator. I have included the code to rotate the image in an onclickfunction of a button. When i press the button for the first time, the image rotates. However, when i press it the next time, nothing happens.

```
 public void displaySpinResult_Spinner(View view) {
        arrow.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because the rotation value is retained. When you specify `rotation(360)` for the second time, the `View` is already rotated by 360degrees, so nothing happens.

You can either try `rotation(arrow.getRotation() + 360)`, or use the [`rotationBy()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewPropertyAnimator.html#rotationBy(float)) method instead.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am now using rotateanimation class and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the solution:

```
public void displaySpinResult_Spinner(View view) {
    arrow.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).start();
    arrow.animate().rotation(360).setInterpolator(new AccelerateDecelerateInterpolator()).reset();
}
```